# Convert String Representation of Code into code

Tags: python-3.x, string, post

I want to build something like leetcode that is a little more tailored to the type of coding that I just want to put in reps for.

I was taking a look at how leetcode does it and it looks like it's a POST request where the code typed in is converted to a string in the body.

For example: https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/

Would have this string in the payload:

```
"class Solution:\n    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:\n        seen = {}\n        \n        for i in range(len(nums)):\n            complement = target - nums[i]\n            if complement in seen:\n                return [seen[complement], i]\n            else:\n                seen[nums[i]] = i\n                "
```

This is the python coded solution:

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        seen = {}
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            complement = target - nums[i]
            if complement in seen:
                return [seen[complement], i]
            else:
                seen[nums[i]] = i
```

My question is:
If I had an API call send me that string representation of the code in the request, how do I convert that into.... code and test against it?

Can assume the backend is also in python. I tried googling this but I couldn't find anything.

As always, thanks!

Comment: This might become particularly dangerous. I would suggest to actually implement a well documented API on top of your applications.

Answer (score -1):

So there's a rather handy function called "exec" in python [(documentation here)](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/exec) which you can use to execute lines of code in string format.

For example:

```
for_loop = "for i in range(3):\n    print(i) #There are 4 spaces here"

exec(for_loop)
>>> 0
>>> 1
>>> 2
```

You would likely first need to parse the string such that it is properly indented and whatnot, which would be up to you, but I'd recommend something on the line of a track-the-number-of-indents-you-need-and-add-4-spaces-each-time-you-need-to-add-indentation strategy. Also I'm not sure how the code you will receive will be formatted to remove ambiguities in indentation, but you might receive the indentations already.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I saw exec and eval. But let's say the code is a class definition. How can I exec the string and then use the class to test against?

Comment: Got it, it's compile and then exec! Should've googled harder. Sorry about that -1!

test_code = 'def hello_world():\n\tprint("Hello World")'
my_func = compile(test_code, "no_name", mode="exec")

exec(my_func)
hello_world()

Comment: @WhitneyChia If the string was valid, the `Solution` class will now be defined.  Make an instance and use it; however, the example you gave is missing `from typing import List` so it fails.